# Add the column in mysql and has the same data like the column existing

Tags: mysql, database

I want to add the column name "payroll_date_on" in the table and has the default value as the other table column named "jo_time_on".

```
ALTER TABLE jobs ADD COLUMN payroll_time_on INT(11)  AS (jo_time_on) PERSISTED;
```

While running this I got an error code

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (jo_time_on) PERSISTED' at line 1
```

Help me to solve this error and clone the column jo_time_on

I am using the mysql version 5.6.38

Comment: Is this a feature of generated columns? What does the manual for your version (as opposed to 5.7) say about generated columns?

Comment: The docs for 5.6 make no mention of the `PERSISTED` keyword.

Comment: Generated columns were introduced in MySQL 5.7, they are not available in your server version. Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE jobs ADD COLUMN payroll_time_on INT(11);
UPDATE TABLE SET payroll_time_on = jo_time_on;
```